# Activar menu desplegable cuando pase el mouse

Tags: html, html5, css

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC, en la cual tengo un menu el cual unos de sus items tiene un sub menu el cual lo oculto aplicando css

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <nav class="menu">
            <div class="icon-list" text-decoration-style:none;>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star-o"></i><span>Mantenimiento</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/Cliente/index">Cliente</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Chinos &amp; Trousers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Underwear</a></li>
                </ul>

                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i><span>Alerts</span></a>

                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i><span>Messages</span></a>

                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i><span>Comments</span></a>

                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>Analytics</span></a>

                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i><span>Reading List</span></a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Menu</button>
    </div>
    <button class="menu-button" id="open-button">Open Menu</button>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="content">
            <header class="codrops-header">
                <div class="codrops-links">
                    <a  href="http://tympanus.net/Development/TabStylesInspiration/"><span></span></a>
                    <a  href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=20100"><span></span></a>
                </div>
            </header>

        </div>
    </div><!-- /content-wrap -->
</div><!-- /container -->
```

CSS

```
<style>
    .menu ul li {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            min-width:140px;
        }
    .menu-wrap .menu ul li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
        }
</style>
```

Con `.menu ul li` oculto el submenu mi problema es que no puedo activarlo cuando paso el mouse por encima del item.

Como se muestra el submenu
[image: sub menu]

Comment: Creo que hay que modificar .menu ul li:hover para remover el display none, antes que sus hijos ul puedan verse.

Comment: @amenadiel Ya lo he intetado de esta manera  .menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
   } pero no funciona.

Comment: Estás modificando la visibilidad del hijo > ul

Comment: Que devo hacer?

Comment: Añadir, además de todo `.menu-wrap .menu il:hover {  display: block;   }`

Comment: Tu codigo no funciona

Comment: Ok ojalá alguien pueda sugerir algo mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, te recomiendo la siguiente estructura. Es mucho más semántica.

```
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="icon-list" text-decoration-style:none;>
    <ul class="main-list">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star-o"></i><span>Mantenimiento</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/Cliente/index">Cliente</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chinos &amp; Trousers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Underwear</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i><span>Alerts</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i><span>Messages</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-o"></i><span>Comments</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i><span>Analytics</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i><span>Reading List</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Segundo, hay que eliminar los `position: absolute` tanto de las `ul` como de los `li`. Además, como ahora `a` y `ul` son hermanos, el `:hover` debe aplicarse al padre, es decir, a los `li`, ya que, si lo dejamos en `a:hover + ul`, al sacar el puntero del `a` se esconderá el submenú.

```
.menu li:hover > ul { 
  display: block; 
} 

.menu a + ul { 
  display: none; 
} 

.menu li:hover > a { 
  text-decoration:none; 
  background-color:#434343;
} 

.menu a + ul > li 
  display: block; 
  min-width:140px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que no puedes hacer `:hover` sobre un elemento que esta oculto, en tu caso estas apuntando el `:hover` sobre el `li` que has iniciado como oculto

```
<style> 
    .menu a:hover + ul {
            background-color:red;
            display: block;
        }

    .menu ul{
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            min-width:140px;
        }   
</style>
```

Yo ocultaría el `ul` y apuntaria el :hover sobre el `<a>` que esta visible siempre y sobre todo porque es un elemento hermano y se encuentra antes que el elemento que quieres modificar, regla imprescindible.

EDITO:

En caso de que no quieras que la lista se sobreponga a lo que hay debajo, quita el `position:absolute;`, quedando finalmente asi:

```
<style> 
    .menu a:hover + ul {
            display: block;
        }

    .menu ul{
            display:none;
            min-width:140px;
        }   
</style>
```

Comment: si funciona pero deseo se desplega por encima del resto de los padres, debería desplegar sin sobreponerse a los padres mas bien extendiendo el menu.

Comment: Actualice la pregunta donde me muestra lo que te indico agregue una imagen.